# Days of the week Django

Tags: django

please, explain me, how do this thing: I have a week number (52, for example) and year (2012). So, how I can get the days number (monday - 24, tuesday - 25, etc). Yes, I read [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html), but I cant understand, how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: The days number... in the month? Year?

Comment: days number in the month)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def get_weekdays(year, week):
    january_first = date(year, 1, 1)
    monday_date = january_first + timedelta(days=week * 7 - january_first.weekday())

    # monday, tuesday, .. sunday
    return [(monday_date + timedelta(days=d)).day for d in range(7)]
```

(my weeks start at monday)